# How to add " ?&max-results= " after the /search/label/LABEL_NAME

Tags: xml, blogger

I want to add post limit and page number navigation on labels posts. So I had limited the post by replacing this `expr:href='data:label.url'` to this `expr:href='data:label.url + "?max-results=6"'` and I found that the link is generating `/search/label/LABEL_NAME?max-results=6` But the Number Navigation is working with `/search/label/LABEL_NAME?&max-results=6`. So When I tried to use `expr:href='data:label.url + "?&max-results=6"'` and save, blogger showing some error.

Comment: Try `expr:href='data:label.url + "?&amp;max-results=6"'` , replace **&** with **&amp;**.

Comment: Thanks, It's working correctly with the labels URLs. But not with the 
" <a href= labels URLs " for menus. So to resolve this issue, I used 
" https://goo.gl/ " URLs Shortener and Just copied the URL with 
" ?&max-result=6 " like 
" http://example.com/search/label/LABEL_NAME?&max-result=6 "
And then generate a short URL and used that in menus. And Now it's perfectly working for me.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to :

```
<b:with value='data:label.url + "?&amp;max-results=7"' var='href'>
    <a expr:href='data:href' rel='tag'><data:label.name/></a>
    <b:if cond='not data:label.isLast'>,</b:if>
</b:with>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a HTML/Javascript Sidebar widget. Code is below:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeURLArg(url,arg,arg_val){ 
    var pattern=arg+'=([^&]*)'; 
    var replaceText=arg+'='+arg_val; 
    if(url.match(pattern)){ 
        var tmp='/('+ arg+'=)([^&]*)/gi'; 
        tmp=url.replace(eval(tmp),replaceText); 
        return tmp; 
    }else{ 
        if(url.match('[\?]')){ 
            return url+'&'+replaceText; 
        }else{ 
            return url+'?'+replaceText; 
        } 
    } 
    return url+'\n'+arg+'\n'+arg_val; 
} 
document.getElementById("Blog1_blog-pager-older-link").href = changeURLArg(document.getElementById("Blog1_blog-pager-older-link").href,"max-results",100) ;
</script>
```